# Display error message on PasswordChangeForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am PasswordChangeForm form to change password. I am trying to display an error message when given password is either less than 8 or greater than 64 (in below code "form.data['new_password1']"). So when I enter password with less than 8 characters, then I am seeing error message "New password should have minimum 8 characters and maximum 64 characters" hit. But error message not displayed on UI page. This is because "return render(request, 'registration/change_password.html'" renders again.

Could you please help me how can we display error message on PasswordChangeForm.

```python
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def change_password_view(request):
   global passwordValidationFailed
   passwordValidationFailed = False

   if (request.method == 'POST'):
       form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)

       if len(form.data['new_password1']) >= 8 and len(form.data['new_password1']) <= 64:
           if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
               messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
                profile = request.user.get_profile()
                profile.force_password_change = False
                profile.save()

                return render(request, 'dau_gui_app/status_view.html', {'title': "System Status"})
            else:
                passwordValidationFailed = False
                messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
        else:
            raise form.ValidationError("New password should have minimum 8 characters and maximum 64 characters")
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)

   return render(request, 'registration/change_password.html', {
              'form': form
            })
```

Here is my change_password.html

```html
{% load i18n %}
{% load admin_static %}{% load firstof from future %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}dir="rtl"{% endif %}>

<head>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/dau_gui_app/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.min.css">
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/static/dau_gui_app/images/favicon.ico' />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/dau_gui_app/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/dau_gui_app/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/dau_gui_app/w3.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/dau_gui_app/dataTables/datatables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/dau_gui_app/dataTables/jQuery-3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/dau_gui_app/dataTables/datatables.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static 'admin/css/base.css' %}{% endblock %}" />
{% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %}

<title>
 {% block title %}Change Password{% endblock %}
</title>

</head>

{% load i18n %}

<body id="login_page">

  <DIV style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding-top:100px;display:block;width:30%">

  <DIV id="login_box">
  <table id="logon_box_table"  >

  <!--  Title Bar -->

  <TR >
  <TD colspan='2' >
   <DIV id='login_box_title'>
      Update Password
     </DIV>
   </TD>
  </TR>


  <!--  Password -->
 <TR >

  <TD >
   <div id= "logon-container" >
     <img src="/static/dau_gui_app/images/logo.png" alt="">
     <div id="alstom-logo-container"> <img src="/static/dau_gui_app/images/alstom_logo.png" alt="" style="width: 90px; height: 18px;"> </div>
    <div id="version-container" >Software Version: 4.0</div>
    </div>
  </TD>

  <TD style="width: 490px; height: 18px;">
      {% block content %}

            <form method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form }}
          </TD>
     </TR>
   <TR >

      <TR >
         <TD colspan='2' style="text-align:center;padding:10px">
            <button type="submit">Update Password</button>
            </form>
                  {% endblock %}
          </TD>
       </TR>

 </TABLE>

</DIV>

</DIV>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not perform validation in the view. Override the `clean()` or `clean_new_password1()` method in the form instead, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute). That way any errors you raise will be added to the form's errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the wrong approach. You should [validate the input in the `Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation), not in the `View`. That's because any error you raise in the form's `full_clean()` process will be caught and added to the form errors, which you display in your template.

In your view, when you do `raise ValidationError(...)`, this actually produces an exception to be raised and hence, you return an HTTP 500 error.

Since you only need to clean one particular field, override the specific field's clean method inside the form as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute):

```
def clean_new_password1(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['new_password1']
    if len(data) < 8 or len(data) > 64:
       raise form.ValidationError("New password should have minimum 8 characters and maximum 64 characters")
    return data
```